# Rails image_tag generating wrong path in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4.2.0 app that uses `image_tag` to display an image, for example:

`= image_tag 'android_green_300_100px'`

(It uses slim also)

In development mode, that generates the following img tag:

```
<img src="/assets/android_green_300_100px-3c57292ef62b34ed33756c2057c8c7320c22ac7fc7061576b29a97d312d954b1.png">
```

which works great.

When deploying to production with capistrano, the image file with the appropiate name is generated:

```
INFO -- : Writing 
/home/app/releases/20160405210757/public/assets/android_green_300_100px-
3c57292ef62b34ed33756c2057c8c7320c22ac7fc7061576b29a97d312d954b1.png
```

But the `image_tag` method returns the image tag:

```
<img src="/images/android_green_300_100px">
```

Which obviously returns a 404 error.

If I manually access the correct image URL, it works (the image is there)

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: show me your railsy `image_tag`

Comment: I call it like this `= image_tag 'android_green_300_100px'` in a slim.html file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty sure you have to use the file extension for image_tag to work in production:

```
= image_tag 'android_green_300_100px.png'
```

Comment: That was the problem! Thank youu!

Comment: I tried adding file name extension (which is PNG of course), but no luck.

Comment: my bad it's working now thanks for the anwer @trosborn

Comment: Very good answer!
But it is a bug? You have a smell what it happens?
development works without extension e production not. It no make sense for me yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your production.rb:

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: I have `config.assets.digest = true`, all css and js files all working, but images won't

Comment: OK, what about set precompile specific assets?
config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif]

Comment: Tried but doesn't work. Apparently the precompilation works, because the image file with the digest is created in `/assets`. The `image_tag` helper is returning a wrong path in production